# Is it possible to use a simple diode and pullup resistor to level shift down in one direction?

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting, logic-level

I'm working on a circuit that involves interfacing with a 3.3v microcontroller (ESP8266) and I'd like to be able to program it using my existing FTDI which operates at 5v. I'm new to level-shifting and looking around I see there are several different approaches. My question relates to a schematic I found for Adafruit's ESP8266 breakout, seen here: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/024/745/original/adafruit_products_schem.png.

For level shifting the RST and RX signals from 5v down to 3.3v, they simply use a diode oriented "backwards" let the internal pullup do the rest. It seems to work like this:

[image]

So my question is, is this a valid approach for unidirectional level shifting? Are there any pitfalls to doing it this way? I couldn't find any other examples of this approach in my searches so I'm not sure if this is just a "quick and dirty" way of doing it or if it only works in this scenario for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signal is traveling from left to right, 5V FTDI output to 3.3V ESP8266 input, then when the FTDI output is LOW, the input to the micro will have a diode drop added to the FTDI LOW output voltage. If the FTDI LOW is at \$100mV\$, then you might expect to add another \$600mV - 700mV\$ to that. You need to check your ESP8266 input specifications to see if the worst case \$800mV\$ still qualifies as a LOW input. Looking at them, I see that the max is \$0.25\cdot V_{cc} = 825mV\$. Which is too close for a lot of comfort. The diode may itself may be on the lower end, though. So perhaps there is a little margin there. It's not a lot, though.

EDIT: Since you have gone the direction of the BSS138, let's drop in a schematic for it and explain it a bit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWO7kT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've added three schematics here using the BSS138 and taken from what you will find on google images, but where I reversed the voltage assignments so that it goes from \$5V\$ to \$3.3V\$. I'd added the NMOS body diode, because it is important. (These circuits are really designed to work from 3.3V to 5V!) The top schematic is the modified version. The lower two below it show what happens when the FTDI driver is driving \$0V\$ in the first instance (left schematic) and is driving \$5V\$ in the second instance (right schematic.) Note that there is a bit of a problem?

Most 3.3V inputs (and I'd guess this is true for the ESP8266) have protection diodes which appear as shown for the very rightmost schematic above. So a *fix* would be to put a series resistor from the NMOS drain to the input pin. This resistor would have to be large enough to limit the current into the protection diodes to meet the specifications (which are almost always \$\le 2mA\$.) In this case, you might choose \$\frac{4.4V-3.3V-600mV}{500\mu A}=1k\Omega\$.

But then the question is... why not just use the resistor and depend upon your protection diodes??

Well, this is often done when going from \$5V\$ to \$3.3V\$. You go read the datasheet, find out the protection diode limits (I wasn't able to find it there), and then compute an appropriate resistor. In this case, I'd probably assume that \$500\mu A\$ is the most I'd be willing to try, given no data, and probably settle on a trial value of \$200\mu A\$ to see how well it works. So in this case, I'd just try a resistor value of \$\frac{5V-3.3V-600mV}{200\mu A}=5.5k\Omega\$ and decide to use either a \$4.7k\Omega\$ or a \$5.6k\Omega\$ for the 3.3V input to the micro, depending upon the protection diodes to do their work.

Or, if you want, you could get yourself a BAV99 and use that externally -- on the idea that you don't want to depend upon the internal protection diodes. If you do this, you might try the last circuit in the bottom right corner of the schematics above.

Comment: You could use a Schottky diode there to improve margin.  Another issue is that with such large pull-ups the rise time will be slow.  May not be important in some applications but in others it can be critical.

Comment: @JohnD: I thought about adding a comment about Schottky diodes. Glad you did. They leak a lot, but probably not enough to cause a problem with the 10k resistor. Agreed also about the possible rise time issues. But that requires more thinking to put quantities to it, so I left that out.

Comment: Thats a good point. This already struck me as a less-than-ideal solution but I didn't even think about the effect of the diode drop. Curious that Adafruit decided to do it this way. What would you recommend instead? Just a simple voltage divider?

Comment: @kcarbone: Do you care if the signal is inverted? Do you prefer mosfets to BJTs, or visa versa? What kind of current compliance does the FTDI chip support for its I/O?

Comment: @jonk: I'd prefer not to invert the signal since it's going to be used for programming the ESP8266. I tend to use mosfets when I can. As for the current supported, honestly I don't know. It's an older FTDI I use typically to program 5v atmega chips. I could just get a 3.3v ftdi but I was curious about how hard it would be to level shift down to from 5v.

Comment: @kcarbone: then use a mosfet. It's great. Have you googled for "level shifter 3.3 5" and then selected the google images thing? You will find LOTS of schematics there. If you feel that they are okay, then I will modify my answer to include a specific design that should be okay here.

Comment: @jonk: Yup, I see the bss138 thrown around a lot so I'll probably try with one of those. Thanks for all your help and info!

Comment: @kcarbone: See my expanded discussion, then. I added a lot for you to consider.